# mail () SMPT error (5050) sending failed 5.1.1) PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am having a problem that I have never encountered in my life.

In practice we have a website where we receive reservations, the A record is pointed towards our vps for the management of the site instead the part of mail is managed by aruba since the customer has preferred to leave their mail client. (for a matter of convenience because they have been using it for some time)

Going to the problem ..
the php mail () function when trying to send an email to the email: info@dominio.it our server returns as an error:
SMPT error (5050) sending failed 5.1.1)
in practice it is as if the email does not exist and was looking for it on our server but in reality it is located on aruba.

How can I tell the php mail () function to search for this mail not locally but on aruba?

with regard
Fabrizio C.

Answer (score 0):

This only lays partial in php itself. You php.ini configuration file allows you to set a few settings

See:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

The rest of the configuration need to be done in the MTA(Mail Transfer Agent) as in outgoing emails server of your VPS. Hard to say what you are using there..

Also according to your text, it looks like you tink the a record had something to do with your email...

a correctly configurated MTA does the following on an email address.

username@domain.tld

It requests the MX requests of domain.tld, and does not use an A record.
Then tries the MX records in order of their priority to deliver the email.

(This also is outside the scope of PHP, but might be good to know)